# Discord.js - TypeError: commandfile.run is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a ytdl Discord Bot and ?play because of that error. Here's my code:

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)))
    if (commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);
```

Again, probably something thats easy to fix, but I cant seem to find the issue here because it worked before. Idk if I messed something up again

my play.js file: https://pastebin.com/4B0DVjWC

Comment: Log `commandfile` to the console. The problem is either that it isn't actually the file (that would go back to your command handler code) or the module doesn't have a `run` property of its exports.

Comment: so the console said it may be because its not in a catch function? So i just put it in a trycatch function (https://pastebin.com/B4mm3ATh). Now I dont get an error message, but the bot still doesnt join

Comment: You're completely ignoring the error in the `catch` block. It's only an unhandled promise rejection warning because it's within an async function without proper error handling. Add `console.error(error);` to your `catch` block and the error will appear again. Also add `console.log(commandfile);` before the `if (commandfile)` statement and share the result.

Comment: I did what you said (https://pastebin.com/59EfywYF) but I still dont get any error message: https://imgur.com/a/4HVvxuE

Comment: Attempt to run a command.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/X221eG1, this is my error, other commands do work, all work except for ?play

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57080616/edit) your answer to include the code in your file for the play command. You're missing the declaration of `module.exports.run`.

Comment: this is my whole play.js file https://pastebin.com/4B0DVjWC

Comment: wym declaration of module.exports.run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your play command file, you're adding a new listener to a new client's `message` event. The code inside of it is only run when the event is emitted, which it won't be. Therefore, `module.exports.run` never gets declared. That means that the object returned by `require()` in your other file doesn't have a `run` property. When you try to call the nonexistent function, your error is thrown.

The format of your file should look like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
// Import other necessary libraries, require files, etc...

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  ...
};

module.exports.config = {
  ...
};
```

Note that I'm *not* adding another listener, but *directly* exporting the functions.

<sub>[Documentation on modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)</sub>

Comment: but isnt that exactly what i did?

Comment: No, your `module.exports.run = ...` line is *within* a new listener. Until that listener fires, `module.exports.run` will be undefined.

Comment: the error is fixed, but now I've got a new one (https://imgur.com/a/xbOnVMj) I dont expect your help on this one because you already helped me with the commandfile.run. TY for your help btw

Comment: You can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Include the code and error *directly* in the question itself. Glad I could help.